# Is it possible to use not effectively final or final variable in lambda body or anonymous class?

Tags: java, lambda, final

Is it possible to use variable which is neither not effectively final nor final, in lamba body?
So is there a way to make the following code compile?

```
class Main {
    interface Test{
        String method();
    }
    void w(){
        String str = "foo";
        str = "bar";
        Test t = () -> str;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.
You can copy your value to **effectively final local variable**:

```
class Main {
    interface Test{
        String method();
    }
    void w(){
        String str = "foo";
        str = "bar";
        String tmpStr = str;
        Test t = () -> tmpStr;
    }
}
```

Since now your temporary value is **effectively final** and you can use it in lambda expressions or anonymous classes.